# How to align the output text in order

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am facing a problem aligning the text in proper format

EX:
say I am to get printout in the following way

```
Name                     Phone No.
Adithya                  99999999999 
Ravi                     99999999999 
Teja                     99999999999
:
:
```

but as the length of the String `Adithya` is not equal to length of `Ravi` we cannot give specific spacing such as

`String s = Name+ "     " + Phone + "\n";`

here if I give so I'll get in the following way

```
Name                Ph
Adithya              9999999
Ravi              9999999
Tej              9999999
:
:
```

it will display in this way. How can I solve this?

Comment: use a custom listview with a name on the top and phone nuumber below. You can set the fontsize.

Comment: Take two TextViews instead of displaying them in one..

Comment: the problem is while getting the output in an e-mail or a printer not while displaying it in the Activity

Comment: @user1785693 Take a screenshot and send it for printer..

Comment: no screen shot is not possible as that activity has other stuff not to be displayed.. i just want a simple logic to maintain the output in a proper format..

Comment: @user1785693 AFAIK , Then the alternative will  be building html page with the above data and display it in the webview. send the same html page for printing..It will best solutions AFAIK and I think it work for sure

Answer (score 0):

This problem is exactly what a `ListView` is designed for.

Use a `ListView` and you can place the Name on the left and the Phone on the right, or any other orientation. You can easily change colors, text size, font, etc.
Find an example for `ListView`. The easy to use simple-adapter is perfect for this implementation.
You should be good to go.

---

I modify this answer here because you have stated in the comment below that you wish to format the phone number list for email and print, rather than for on-screen display.

This is now a difficult problem for several reasons:

- Email doesn't obey tabs.
- Tabs are non-optimal because longer and shorter names will need a
  different number of tab characters.

**The only solution I can think of for email and general print output is to calculate the number of space characters necessary between the name and phone number columns* and force printing with a mono-space font such as "Courier", etc.**

(*) How to calculate the number of spaces required between columns: Choose a row position for the phone number column, i.e. 40 characters. The number of space characters required between name and phone for any specific row is `(40 - name.length())`.

Your code will look something like this:

```
String text = "Phone List:";
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    String name = names[i];
    String phone = phones[i];
    int nsp = 40 - name.length();
    text += "\n" + name + StringUtils.repeat(" ", nsp) + phone;
}
```

Comment: Not good to use ListView untill it is necessary. Because ListView has build with lot of optimizations and recycling. For the small thing like this. LinearLayout or TableLayout with scrollview is best option

Comment: Good point @Pragnani. Both methods can work. But I still think ListView is better. This is because using a LinearLayout for each column or a TableLayout will require two separate parallel lists: one for names and one for phone numbers. This is both bad programming as the lists can get out of sync and will cause misalignment if any item in either list word-wraps. Plus, the overhead and development effort for SimpleAdapter ListView is not very high at all once you get used to it.

Comment: This problem is while sending the String to a E-Mail or a printer not while displaying in the Activity..

Comment: How do you make it with listview without taking Two textviews in simpleAdapter..?

Comment: @Pragnani- this is not to display in the Activity it is while getting a printout where only one string can be place..

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to upvote (triangle) and accept (check) correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use tab (`\t`):

```
String s = String.format("%s\t\t%s\n", Name, Phone);
```

This will enter two tabs after the name and then the phonenumber. The phonenumbers should be aligned nicely.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will fail because a) tab characters are usually processed as a fixed number of spaces in email and b) longer and shorter names will require different numbers of tab characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you to use `Table Layout` (it will guarantee you alignment) instead of making your code complex.

The following will be the layout for your `list view` ROW
Your coding part will be same just switch to this new layout

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:stretchColumns="1">


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tblRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
            android:padding="5dip">


      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/tv_Name" 
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_weight="3"   <!--it defines how much space this view should get in row-->
          android:text="Ravi"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:paddingLeft="20dip"
          android:textSize="14sp"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

       <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/tv_PhoneNumber" 
          android:layout_width="0dip"
          android:layout_weight="3"
          android:text="9999999999"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:paddingLeft="20dip"
          android:textSize="14sp"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>   

      </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

[image]

Then bind this layout to your adapter like you do with other Layouts..