# java spacing when writing to a file

Tags: java

just a beginner in java doing a simple reading file processing some data and writing to a file, however whenever I print to a file I get this inconsistent spacing such as shown below. Especially the zeros are throwing me off. Right now I am padding the strings with empty spaces but I am sure there are better suggestions out there to have consistent spacing between strings in a file. Thanks for the help. I have attached a picture of the inconsistent printing, especially the zeros.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576406/how-to-align-the-output-text-in-order

Answer (score 0):

In Apache Commons [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) library there are convenient methods to set the proper pad - e.g. `rightPad` seems to be useful in your case - you could make something like

```
String row = StringUtils.rightPad(firstValue, lengthOfTheLongestValueInColumn1 + definedColumnMargin) + StringUtils.rightPad(secondValue, lengthOfTheLongestValueInColumn2 + definedColumnMargin) // + ... etc
```

If these `lengthOfTheLongestValueInColumn` variables would be calculated dynamically then it would work perfectly but you could also just hardcode some reasonable value (if you know that no value will be longer than, let say, `20` it could have value of `20`)

Answer (score 0):

I think best option will be to use String format

```
return String.format("%1$" + length + "s", inputString)
```

where length is max size of your digit

you can read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)